# Android - AES decryption failing with strange content lengths

Tags: android, encryption, aes

i am trying to decode an AES encrypted data that i get from a webservice.
The encrypted length is: 4256 bytes
The decrypted length is: 4247 bytes

Baiscally i think that would be ok because of some padding or something...
BUT. the data actually decrypts fine to plain text. Except that some characters are missing at the end.

What could possibly cause the missing characters at the end?

Here comes my decryption code:

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] input) throws Exception {
    byte[] rawKey = getKey("bla".getBytes());
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
    AlgorithmParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, iv);
    return cipher.doFinal(input);
}
```

Comment: Did you (or the webservice, actually) use the same mode (specially padding) for encryption?

Comment: Also note: CBC with a constant initialization vector is not a secure mode. You want to use a new randomly-generated initialization vector for each message (and transmit it together with the message).

Comment: i know that, but unfortunately i don't have access to the server side code and this is the config that is used on the server side (.NET) to do the encrytion. And it seems to work, since 90% of the text is decrypted corretly...

Comment: facing issue it does not decrypt first 16 or 19 characters any idea why? how you overcome your problem in my case content length is same  any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as an answer because it's too long for a comment :(

Problem solved, it never was the decryption that was causing the error. Decryption was fine.

The actual problem was me, trying to convert the string to a json object while it was a json array.

That in combination with a logcat limit of 4k characters masked to actual json error messages and cut off my debug messages (so there never were any characters missing)...

Answer (score 0):

As Paŭlo says, the problem is almost certainly in the padding.  Set up a test `decrypt()` method with no padding: "AES/CBC/NoPadding" IIRC.  Decrypt the same cyphertext and have a look at the actual bytes of padding that have been added to the end of the message.  That should tell you what padding (if any) is actually being added to the message.